# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, api

So I m trying add data into MongoDB and display it and I am able input data in it but unable to display it as it says Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title') for any info from the API

post.js where I want to display API data

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
    </div>
```

form.js from where I am inputtiing data in API

```
const Form = () => {
  const [postData, setpostData] = useState({
    creator: "",
    title: "",
    mesage: "",
    tags: "",
    selectedFile: "",
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createPost(postData))
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setpostData({
      creator: "",
      title: "",
      message: "",
      tags: "",
      selectedFile: "",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="form-container">
      <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h1 id="create-memory">Create a Memory</h1>
        <div id="form-input">
          <input className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Creator"
            value={postData.creator}

            onChange={(e) =>
              setpostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })
            }
          />
          <input className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="title"
            value={postData.title}
            onChange={(e) => setpostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="message"
            value={postData.mesage}
            onChange={(e) => setpostData({ ...postData, mesage: e.target.value })}
          />
          <input className="form-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="tags"
            value={postData.tags}
            onChange={(e) => setpostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value })}
          />
        </div>
        <FileBase
          type="file"
          multiple={false}
          onDone={({ base64 }) =>
            setpostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })
          }
        />
        <div id="form-button">
          <button className="form-button">Submit</button>
          <button className="form-button" onClick={clear}>Clear</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

post.js it displays the whole post

```
const Posts = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  console.log(posts);
  return (
    !posts.length ? <h1>nothing to show</h1> : (
      <div>
        {
          posts.map((post) => (
            <Post />
          ))
        }
      </div>
```

API js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:5000/posts';

export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
```

Comment: You should be passing the `post` to the Post component: `<Post post={post} />`

Comment: in `post.js it displays the whole post` are you sure you are passing post data. i think you forget to pass change `<Post />` to `<Post post={post}  />`